# Can I connect a mobile charger of output 5v 2amps to power a 3-6v dc mini motor pump of current intake 130-220mA?

Tags: current, dc, charger

I wanted to power a 3-6v dc mini motor pump using mobile charger do I need to use a limiter to control the current since motor requires only 130-220mA and charger output is 2A

Comment: It should be fine, 5V is within the pump ratings, and 2A should be enough to cover the higher current needed to start the pump.

Comment: JOSE LOWRANCE - Hi, When the helpful [comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/538208/can-i-connect-a-mobile-charger-of-output-5v-2amps-to-power-a-3-6v-dc-mini-motor#comment1393303_538208) above from *Brian Drummond* is added, [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings) previous question answers your main point, about whether a current limiter is needed.

Comment: (Just FYI, although commonly called a "mobile charger", they are not actually a *charger* as they don't know anything about the specific voltage and current regulation profile, needed to charge the mobile phone battery. They are just a power supply. The charger is an internal part of the mobile phone, which gets its power from that external power supply.)